# My height isnt working in CSS?

Tags: css, height

I have a page that I want the height to automatically adjust based on content, but if I do `height:100%;`, `height:auto;`, or `min-height:100%;`, it doesn't work. What can I do to fix this?

Here's my website page: http://ht.io-web.com/tutor-registration

Comment: code example, or better yet, jsfiddle.net

Comment: This question has been answered time and time again. Check all the related items on the right.

Comment: If you come here to claim that something basic, which works fine for everyone else, is not working for you, then the burden is on you to provide the relevant code.  Only linking to a URL is inadequate as it forces the reader to dig through your code, as well as the fact that whenever the page is edited you make the question useless to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting a height when you only want it to expand to the dimensions of its contents? If you leave out height, it will expand as needed as you fill the container with content.
Could you describe the problem in your page in more detail, and possible give us a code example? I will update my answer to better help you.

From the links you gave, it looks like you need to clear your floats. Try adding `overflow:auto;` to the container div in question.

Comment: When I take off the height:500px it just goes down to the min-height which is set at 200px and if I take that off it gets even smaller. I just took off the height and min-height to show you what I mean. http://ht.io-web.com/tutor-registration

Comment: So the container in question is `p_lt_zoneContent_wP_wP_lt_zoneLower_logonform_pnlBody`? Where/What is the CSS for that div?

Comment: I can't find the css for your divs. If you give us an example, or at least tell us where it is, it would help. Like Sparky said, a posted example of your css problem would be most useful.

Comment: I'm sorry I dont mean to be a burden. '.home-lower' is the class.
Here is the URL for my code. 
http://ht.io-web.com/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?stylesheetname=hireatutor 
I dont know if this is what you want but thanks.

Comment: If you are floating divs in the container, you might need to clear your floats. Try adding `overflow:auto;` to the container div in question; see if that helps.

Comment: Thats it!!! Thank you sooo much! If i could vote for you I would!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked. You can click the checkmark to mark as accepted answer :)